# Polymer injectBoundHTML() not working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, event-handling, polymer

element that shows events. The events come from a JSON file and are loaded by `core-ajax`

It has a detail and a non-detail template, which can be toggled.
At first the non Detail template is loaded, then you can toggle additional information and the seccond template is loaded.

```
    <template if="{{showDetail}}"  >
        <core-ajax auto
        response="{{data}}"
        on-core-response="{{ajaxHandler}}"
        url ="http://localhost:8080/myevents/getDetailEvent={{nummer}}"; 
        handleAs="json"></core-ajax>

    <div class="showbox" >
        <h2 id= "title"> </h2>

        <p><b>Start:</b> {{data.startDate }}</p>
        <p><b>Ende:</b> {{data.endDate }}</p>

         <p id = "place"></p> </br>
         <p id = "description"></p> </br>
         <p id = "manager"></p> </br>
         <button on-tap="{{toggleView}}">Less</button>
    </div>
    </template>
```

Non-Detail Template

```
    <template if="{{!showDetail}}" >
        <core-ajax auto
        response="{{data}}"
        on-core-response="{{ajaxHandler}}"
        url ="http://localhost:8080/myevents/getEvent={{number}}"; 
        handleAs="json"></core-ajax>

        <div class="showbox" >
            <h2 id= "title"> </h2>
            <p><b>Start:</b> {{data.startDate}}</p>
            <p id = "description"></p> </br>
            <button on-tap="{{toggleView}}">More</button>
        </div>
    </template>
```

In my JSON I have a lot of HTML Tags thats why I use `injectBoundHTML()` to output them on my Screen. Here is my `dataChanged` method, which gets called when the component is loaded the first time, or I click the toggle Button:

```
    dataChanged : function() {

    if (this.data){

        if(this.showDetail) {
            this.injectBoundHTML(this.data.titleDe, this.$.titleDe);
            this.injectBoundHTML(this.data.description, this.$.description);
            this.injectBoundHTML(this.data.manager, this.$.manager);
        } else {

            this.injectBoundHTML(this.data.titleDe, this.$.titleDe);
            this.injectBoundHTML(this.data.description, this.$.description);
        }
    }
}
```

When the component is loaded the first time, `injectBoundHTML()` is working and injects all of the content coming from the json. When I push the toggle Button no injection takes place! If I add the JSON content in the `dataChanged` MEthod without injection, it works!

What am I doing wrong?